# ¿Dónde puedo encontrar las bibliotecas de ChemAxon para un proyecto de Java?

Tags: java, java-import

Quiero utilisar Molecule, una clase que fue dasarollado por ChemAxon una empressa que desarolla soluciones de software y servicios para química y biología. Sin embargo no sé dónde puedo encontrar las bibliotecas que utilise un professor que tengo que probar el proyecto de Java que creó.

Aqui esta un ejemplo de una clase donde utiliso esta otra clase

```
package src.caos.aaai;

import java.util.Collection;

import test.ViewJTable;

import src.caos.aaai.OperatorLibrary.Operator.GroundedOperator;
import chemaxon.reaction.ReactionException;
import chemaxon.reaction.Reactor;
import chemaxon.sss.search.SearchException;
import chemaxon.struc.Molecule;
import chemaxon.struc.RxnMolecule;

public class State {
    private Molecule molecule;
    private boolean isStartingMaterial;
    int hash;

    public State(Molecule molecule, boolean solved) {
        this.molecule = molecule;
        this.isStartingMaterial = solved; 

        // This could fail if cxsmarts doesn't auto-canonicalize...
        // which is safe, albeit inefficient, if the only use is as a cache
        this.hash = molecule.toFormat("cxsmarts").hashCode();  

    }

    public Molecule getMolecule() {
        return this.molecule;
    }

    public boolean isGoal() {
        return isStartingMaterial;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (! (obj instanceof State)) return false;
        if (this.hash != ((State)obj).hash) return false;
        try {
            return MolecularUtils.molecularEquivalence(this.molecule, ((State)obj).getMolecule());
        } catch (SearchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getMolecule().toFormat("cxsmarts");
    }

    public int size() {
        return  molecule.getAtomCount();
    }

}
```

El código completo del proyecto, un algoritmo de búsqueda de número de prueba para la planificación química, se puede encontrar [aquí](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~aheifets/ChemicalPlanning/).

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Es esto lo que buscas [git](https://github.com/ChemAxon/jklustor-web-example)

Comment: @RaulCacacho Es raro, parece lo que estoy buscando pero no puedo encontrar la molécula `chemaxon.struc.Molecule` por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que tienen [su propio repositorio](https://chemaxon.com/news/chemaxon-maven-repository) [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).

Por lo que puedes agregar las siguientes líneas dependiendo el sistema de construcción que estés usando:

[gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle)

```
repositories {
  maven {
     url "https://hub.chemaxon.com/artifactory/libs-release"
     credentials {
         username = E-MAIL
         password = API-KEY
     }
  }
}
```

[maven](/questions/tagged/maven)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>chemaxon</id>
      <url>https://hub.chemaxon.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

y en tu `settings.xml`

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>chemaxon</id>
        <username>E-MAIL</username>
        <password>API-KEY</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```